# Медиа запросы меньше 1024рх

Tags: css, media-queries

вопрос такой. Есть класс

```
.tickets {
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 130px;
}
```

и я задал ему м запрос

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .tickets { margin-left: 60px; }
}
```

но он не работает.

Comment: @media screen and (min-width:  1024px) {...}

Comment: Это не помогает

Comment: Нужно что бы ниже этих рх отступ уменьшился

Comment: Используйте @media screen and (max-width: 1024px)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Медиа запросы меньше 1024рх

Если Вы хотите, чтобы свойства работали на экранах шириной меньше 1024px, нужно в медиа-запросе указать значение `max-width: 1024px`.

[Результат на CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/KKPzmwv)